# Intermitent Yahoo Oauth2 invalid_redirect_uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo, invalid-request-uri

I am working on allowing users to log in to my website using Yahoo. I have intermittent problems with Yahoo Oauth2.  I will generate the url to request the authorization code and it will get to the Yahoo login sometimes.  Other times I will get the window with "Uh oh Looks like something went wrong. Please try again later. Developers: Please specify a valid request and submit again." and the url will have error=invalid_request&error_description=invalid+redirect+uri

My request url is configured on the yahoo console.  Also I am using https on a server connected to the internet (not a local machine)

My request authorization was created using the one in https://developer.yahoo.com/sign-in-with-yahoo
I have
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?
client_id={MY CLIENT D}
&scope=openid
&nonce=4c29ac770b9b1d795b
&prompt=consent
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F{MY WEB SITE}%2Fcallback_yahoo.php

I am out of ideas at this point.
Thank you

Comment: maybe some of your params are not url-encoded that can sometimes breaks url and make invalid redirect-uri?

Comment: Hello. first,  thank you for trying to help.  The thing is that I will be able to log in the app.  then I logout, then when I try again I will get the error. And its the same redirect url every time.

Comment: do you regenerate and url-encode `nonce` for every request? just ask for clarity, maybe someone experienced in yahoo can help.

Comment: Does the Sample URL in this page works for you? (Replacing your Client ID and redirect_url) https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html#i-setting-up-create-an-application-and-get-oauth-2-0-credentials

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (maybe) something was wrong on Yahoos side.  I created another application with the SAME configuration and the problem seem to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I think the yahoo api for updating redirect uris is pretty abysmal as it is eventually consistent. It's as if there are multiple replicas eventually updated but it is pretty slow. For example I'm right now still waiting for more than a day update.